# PySpark join return an empty dictionary not None

Tags: python, pyspark, pagerank

I have an RDD:

```
[('4', 1),
 ('1', 1),
 ('8', 1),
 ('9', 1),
 ('10', 1),
 ('2', 1),
 ('3', 1),
 ('5', 1),
 ('6', 1),
 ('7', 1),
 ('11', 1)]
```

I am trying to leftOuterJoin() this RDD with another:

```
[('2', ({'3': 1}, 1)),
 ('3', ({'2': 1}, 1)),
 ('4', ({'1': 1, '2': 1}, 2)),
 ('5', ({'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}, 3)),
 ('6', ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2)),
 ('7', ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2)),
 ('8', ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2)),
 ('9', ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2)),
 ('10', ({'5': 1}, 1)),
 ('11', ({'5': 1}, 1))]
```

Thus, one my records returned is

```
('1', (1, None)),
```

For reference, other records look like:

```
[('4', (1, ({'1': 1, '2': 1}, 2))),
```

This is causing me problems as I need to deal with the data later, and I need an empty dictionary, not a None. I.e. `('1', (1, ({}, 0)))` What would be a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this with a `map`, and test for `None`:

```
def rep(r):
  if r[1][1] == None:
    return (r[0], (r[1][0],({},0)))
  return r

rdd_left.leftOuterJoin(rdd_right).map(rep).collect()
```

This yields the desired output on your example data.